# How do you center the content in a scrollview?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, swift2

I know this should be a very easy problem to solve, but I don´t seem to get the desired result.

I have horizontally scrolling UIScroll view with a width of 320. The width of its content is 467. I also have vertically scrolling UIScroll view with a hight of 310. The height of its content is 467 as well.

After searching for answers on the internet, the closest I have come to a solution is this:

```
CGFloat newContentOffsetX = (ScrollView.contentSize.width/2) - (ScrollView.bounds.size.width/2);
ScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(newContentOffsetX, 0);
```

The code is getting errors, maybe because it was written in 2013 . And I know this code would only center the content horizontally.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

I usually set the contentOffset inside viewDidLayoutSubviews, similar to the code snippet below.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Center the ScrollView content
    let centerOffsetX = (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width) / 2
    let centerOffsetY = (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) / 2
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerOffsetX, y: centerOffsetY)
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(centerPoint, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code I use in my apps

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetX = scrollView.bounds.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width ? (scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    let offsetY = scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height ? (scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;
    _imageView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width / 2 + offsetX, scrollView.contentSize.height / 2 + offsetY);
}
```